# NLog use in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nlog

How can I use NLog to get detail information regarding a local error?

Until now I have this:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        var domain = db.Works.ToList();

        var model = Mapper.Map<IList<Work>, IList<WorkIndexViewModels>>(domain);

        return View(model);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Error("Error in Index: " + e);
    }
}
```

If I put the return after the catch, the model is out of scope.

If I put the return inside the try, I get "not all code path returns a value" from the Action.

So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've already captured the error and you can't show the requested page, you could redirect within the catch to your error page:

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Error("Error in Index: " + e);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error"); // Redirect to error controller or page
    }
```

Alternatively, and probably more appropriate, you could have your action raise a 500 error so that your error configuration within your web.config can properly handle redirection.

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Error("Error in Index: " + e);
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500); // Raise internal server error
    }
```